# Will my tub leak without the toe-touch (pop-up) stopper?

Tags: bathtub

I want to remove but not replace my toe touch stopper. I would like to use a strainer that I can remove and clean and then some sort of top when I want to use for bath rather than shower. Does removing the toe touch create some kind of leakage if I don’t replace it?

Comment: "Toe touch stopper" is a push to operate drain plug? Removing that won't cause any leak.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you manage to crack or break the plastic drain pipe below the tub while you're removing the stopper (which would be highly unlikely unless you're resorting to large tools), there is absolutely nothing that will cause any leakage by not having the stopper in place.

Our pop-up stopper broke. Replacing it just hasn't been high on the priority list, so we pulled it out years ago. For the occasions when we need a bath, we've got a little rubber stopper we put in there.